# How can I import a PostgreSQL .pgc file into a Postgres DB

Tags: database, postgresql, import, migration

I am expecting a data set to be supplied for data migration into a new system. The legacy vendor has supplied me with a .pgc file.

- What is this? Is this a data file? Google tells me its an embedded SQL Program.
- How can I import this to my local Postgres DB to get at the data set?

The output of command file filename.pgc is

```
file energyresourcingprod.pgc
energyresourcingprod.pgc: PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.12-0
```

The first few lines from text editor are:

```
PGDMPrenergyresourcingprod9.2.49.2.4∑±00ENCODINGENCODINGSET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
false≤00
STDSTRINGS
STDSTRINGS)SET standard_conforming_strings = 'off';
false≥126214581287energyresourcingprodDATABASErCREATE DATABASE energyresourcingprod WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'C' LC_CTYPE = 'C';
$DROP DATABASE energyresourcingprod;
carerixfalse26152200publicSCHEMACREATE SCHEMA public;
DROP SCHEMA public;
```

The file is 300Mb and the majority of it contains hashed/base64? content:

```
ßû+˜)™yä⁄%(»j9≤\§^¸S∏Cîó|%ëﬂsﬁ∆†p1ñºúíñ Í∆î≈3õµ=qn
Mµ¢©]Q,uÆ<*Å™ííP’ÍOõ…∫U1EuÍˇ IîﬁärJ¥›•$ø...
...
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Please show the first few lines of the file, and the output of the command `file thefilename.pgc` .

Comment: If it is indeed C-Embedded SQL, then it isn't a data set at all, but a *program* written in C, that must be preprocessed using the `ecpg` tool, then compiled and run. Your vendor should be able to assist you with this. The embedded program may contain the data set, may generate it, or may be something unrelated to what you actually wanted.

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger, I have added detail to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a plain PostgreSQL dump.

Use [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) to load it into a database.

It's weird that they used that filename, but ultimately insignificant.